# jQuery Change event not firing at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, eonasdan-datetimepicker

In my Edit view I have a textbox that accepts `Date`'s.

Using MVC, when I go to the Edit View, the fields are already filled in with that record's information which is fine.

But, I want to set an event listener on one of the fields, specifically the field that accepts dates as stated above.

When i go to the page, I check the source and it looks like this for that field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DateEntered">Date Entered:</label>
    <div style="width:26.5%" class="col-md-10">
        <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-group date">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="DateEnteredPhase" name="DateEntered" type="datetime" value="09/21/2016" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="DateEntered" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice how the value is `"09/21/2016"` which is correct at first.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#DateEnteredPhase').change(function () {
            var dateString = $('#DateEnteredPhase').val();
            alert(dateString);
        });
    });
});
```

Now, I have changed the date value in that textbox to `"09/22/2016"`, and the change event is not firing.  Also when I check the source **after** I change the date, the value still says `"09/21/2016"` and not `"09/22/2016"`.

When I plug this into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ot8jznb/), the change event is firing appropriately.

How do I fix this?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Where the [DateTimePicker (by eonasdan)](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) is initialized in jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    });
});
```

Comment: is the code in your project and this Fiddle same?? I doubt so. I think you have used a dateTime picker plugin.. let me know if I am wrong

Comment: The JSFiddle demonstrates that the code works as designed.  Unless you can actually demonstrate the problem, I don't see what we can do.

Comment: Do you programatically change the value? Keep in mind that such changes via code are not triggering the `change` event! The event only gets fired when you change the field manually ...

Comment: @Reddy I have updated the question with the code that is supplied in the source on the page.

Comment: @eisbehr I am manually changing the value in the textbox

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I still feel its not sufficient, Ok let me know why do have so much of markup when you just need a textbox ie: a input element??

Comment: @Reddy This markup is so that the user doesn't have to manually write in the date. The `<span>`'s create a calendar add-on so the user can click it and select the date.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid exactly..  So that means you are using a Datetime picker plugin. Can you share us the plugin documentation site

Comment: read this it may help you understand how change event works. for this kind of input the change event is triggered when you press or blur(lose focus). so arrows changes or just change the number without leaving the input or pressing enter will not emit the change event. If you want that to be live, you may consider doing on keypress, keypressup or keypressdown event.

Comment: @Reddy https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid great, Now can you add the code where you initialize the dateTime picker in your jquery

Comment: @DincaAdrian after the user chooses a date, that date is populated into the textbox and then focus is no longer in that textbox automatically

Comment: @Reddy i just updated the question

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid gave you my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem** : Is after you apply the plugin the user has to just change the date via the calendar displayed on the UI, And **the plugin will programatically change the date, This will not trigger your change event**.

**Solution** : **use the plugin built in event handler to catch the change event** and then execute your code. So the below code must work. Here is the change event details from **[Plugin Documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange)**

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    });

   //add change event listner that plugin supports
   $('#datetimepicker').on('dp.change',function(e){
     alert(e.date);
   })

});
```

Comment: ahh got it! Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If the source is generated dynamically - events will not bind to elements on document ready. Try this.

```
$(document).on("change", "#DateEnteredPhase", function () {
    var dateString = $('#DateEnteredPhase').val();
    alert(dateString);
});
```

Comment: well the only thing I could say - if it's not working - you are using too old version of jQuery, or there is no "change" event on element with id "DateEnteredPhase".